# Making new pandas multiindex df from original multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe, df1, pulled from yahoo using yfinance, with a timeseries index and two-level multiindex columns. Level 0 is 'adj close', 'high' and 'volume', and level 1 is a list of company symbols, like this:

|  | Adj Close |  |  | High |  |  | Volume |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | C1 | C2 | C3 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| Date |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 02-01-2020 | 12.78 | 41.73 | 24.03 | 13.50 | 41.77 | 26.43 | 100000 | 1234300 | 23454 |
| 03-01-2020 | 12.29 | 41.11 | 23.61 | 12.77 | 42.09 | 23.99 | 100022 | 1555555 | 23999 |

Im trying to make a new dataframe, df2, by making calculations on the columns of df1.

For example, using the same timeseries index, Id like to make the first *column* in the new dataframe, df2, the percent increase for each of the (level 1) symbols in the (level 0) price column of df1. Then *columns* in df2 being rolling moving average of the Price (level 0) each symbol (level 1). Also a column that writes a boolean True if the High of today is higher than the Adj Close of yesterday.

Basically, each *column* in df2 will be made by manipulating level 0 data from the corresponding level 1 company symbols in df1.

(Im saying *column* I now know its not a column, but a group of columns grouped by the level 0)

So I wrote a function:

```
def indicators_df(df1):
    
    # Create a new DataFrame with the same index as df1
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index)
           
    # Plus / minus change %
    df2['Pct'] = df1['Adj Close'].pct_change().fillna(0)
    
    # Price MAs
    df2['$10MA'] = df1['Adj Close'].rolling(window=10).mean()
    df2['$20MA'] = df1['Adj Close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
    df2['$50MA'] = df1['Adj Close'].rolling(window=50).mean()
    df2['$100MA'] = df1['Adj Close'].rolling(window=100).mean()
    df2['$200MA'] = df1['Adj Close'].rolling(window=200).mean()
    
    # Volume MAs
    df2['V10MA'] = df1['Volume'].rolling(window=10).mean()
    df2['V20MA'] = df1['Volume'].rolling(window=20).mean()
    df2['V50MA'] = df1['Volume'].rolling(window=50).mean()
    df2['V100MA'] = df1['Volume'].rolling(window=100).mean()
    df2['V200MA'] = df1['Volume'].rolling(window=200).mean()
    
    return df2
```

which returns this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column Pct
```

I tried loads of variations, but kept getting the same error until I realised (I think...) Im trying to put the results for all the level 1 company symbols in one column in the new dataframe, df2, which is not multiindex.

So how would I write the function correctly, creating a new multiindex dataframe where the level 0 values/keys (not sure of the correct terminology) are the calculations Ive made on df1, such as percent change, rolling average etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, as a simple approach, you can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) multiple [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) on a predefined pair of computations :

```
def indicators_df(df):
    def xs(df, m):
        return df.xs(m, axis=1, drop_level=False)

    def rn(df, d):
        return df.rename(d, axis=1, level=0)

    pct = (df.pipe(xs, "Adj Close").pct_change()
           .fillna(0).pipe(rn, {"Adj Close": "Pct"}))

    tmp = df.pipe(xs, "High")
    chk = tmp.eq(tmp.shift()).pipe(rn, {"High": "Check"})
    
    _map = {k: [(w, f"{pre}{w}MA") for w in [10, 20, 50, 100, 200]]
            for k, pre in [("Adj Close", "$"), ("Volume", "V")]}

    pvs = [df.pipe(xs, l0).rolling(b).mean().pipe(rn, {l0:l1})
           for (l0, p) in _map.items() for (b,l1) in p]

    return pd.concat([pct, chk, *pvs], axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(indicators_df(df))

             Pct              Check         ... V100MA     V200MA        
              C1    C2    C3     C1     C2  ...     C2  C3     C1  C2  C3
Date                                        ...                          
02-01-2020  0.00  0.00  0.00  False  False  ...    NaN NaN    NaN NaN NaN
03-01-2020 -0.04 -0.01 -0.02  False  False  ...    NaN NaN    NaN NaN NaN

[2 rows x 36 columns]
```

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'index': ['02-01-2020', '03-01-2020'],
     'columns': [
         ('Adj Close', 'C1'), ('Adj Close', 'C2'), ('Adj Close', 'C3'),
         ('High', 'C1'), ('High', 'C2'), ('High', 'C3'), ('Volume', 'C1'),
         ('Volume', 'C2'),('Volume', 'C3')],
     'data': [[12.78, 41.73, 24.03, 13.5, 41.77,
               26.43, 100000, 1234300, 23454],
              [12.29, 41.11, 23.61, 12.77, 42.09,
               23.99, 100022, 1555555, 23999]],
     'index_names': ['Date'],
     'column_names': [None, None]}, orient='tight')
```

Comment: Thanks... I tried in my code, and opened a new notebook, and both times I get: NameError: name 'i' is not defined. I swapped for k and got a result. However... your code is waaay above my level, so Im going to go through it line by line. No doubt Ill learn quite a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, we need to change `i` to `w`. I updated my answer. Feel free to ask any question ;)

Comment: Thank again. I dont pretend to understand your code yet, and pvs is waaaay beyond my current level of understanding, but Ive been working with it and I do have questions.... 1) you define the function xs(df, m), but when you call it later, df.pipe(xs, "Adj Close").pct_change() you dont specify any parameters? Why? Also, I was unaware of pipe()...  2) In pct you piped 2 functions, which seems to be the idea, but in tmp and chk you dont... any reason? I ask because df.xs("High", axis=1) seems to do the same as df.pipe(xs, "High"). Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
import pandas as pd

def indicators_df(df1):
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index)

    for col in df1.columns.levels[1]:
        
        df2[('Pct', col)] = df1['Adj Close', col].pct_change().fillna(0)
        
        df2[('$10MA', col)] = df1['Adj Close', col].rolling(window=10).mean()
        df2[('$20MA', col)] = df1['Adj Close', col].rolling(window=20).mean()
        df2[('$50MA', col)] = df1['Adj Close', col].rolling(window=50).mean()
        df2[('$100MA', col)] = df1['Adj Close', col].rolling(window=100).mean()
        df2[('$200MA', col)] = df1['Adj Close', col].rolling(window=200).mean()
        
        df2[('V10MA', col)] = df1['Volume', col].rolling(window=10).mean()
        df2[('V20MA', col)] = df1['Volume', col].rolling(window=20).mean()
        df2[('V50MA', col)] = df1['Volume', col].rolling(window=50).mean()
        df2[('V100MA', col)] = df1['Volume', col].rolling(window=100).mean()
        df2[('V200MA', col)] = df1['Volume', col].rolling(window=200).mean()
        
    return df2
```

Comment: Thanks. Intuitively, this is the method Id have tried (if I knew how!). I used your code and it produced this: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [02-01-2020, 03-01-2020, then pages of red saying: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()